# Getting WebSockets to Work with Nginx and Asp.Net Core on Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, c#, nginx, asp.net-core, websocket

I am trying to get web sockets working inside a Asp.Net Core app that is hosted under nginx inside Raspberry Pi.

My default  file settings are:

```
location /the_socket/ {
    proxy_pass http://websocket:8090/;
}
```

in class the websocket (using Fleck) is opened like:

```
   var server = new WebSocketServer("ws://0.0.0.0:8090/the_socket");
    server.Start(
        socket =>
        {
                socket.OnOpen = () =>
                {

                };
                socket.OnClose = () =>
                {

                };
                socket.OnMessage = message =>
                {

                };
        });
```

This is my calling JavaScript:

```
url = "ws://the_socket:8090";
$(document).ready(function () {

    function Connect() {
        try {
            $("#lblConnectionStatus").html("Reconnecting...");
            if (ws instanceof WebSocket) {
                ws.close();
            }
            ws = new WebSocket(url);
            ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";
            ws.onerror = function (e) {
                $("#divInternalMessangingStatus").html("Internal Messaging Error: " + e.message);
            };
            ws.onclose = function () {
                $("#divInternalMessangingStatus").html("Internal Messaging Closed:");
                Connect();
            };
            ws.onopen = function () {
                $("#divInternalMessangingStatus").html("Client connected");

            };
            ws.onmessage = function (e) {
                $("#divInternalMessangingStatus").html(e.data);
            };
        } catch (err) {
            $("#divInternalMessangingStatus").html(err);
        }
    }

    Connect();
});
```

Which errors on Connection Refused...

NB

I had tried changing:

```
location /the_socket/ {
    proxy_pass http://websocket:8090/;
}
```

to:

```
location /the_socket/ {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8090/;
}
```

Comment: im trying the same and its not working but works locally could you tell me more.. im getting 'The server returned status code '200' when status code '101' was expected.'